# Error sh: 1: read: arg count

Tags: bash, shell, read, dash

I want to simply wait for the user to acknowledge a message by pressing <kbd>Return</kbd>. In bash, I am able to call

```
$ read

$
```

However, in sh (dash in my case), I get

```
$ read
sh: 1: read: arg count
$
```

It seems like I *must* provide an argument? Where does that difference come from?

Comment: I'd start by typing `type read` plus Return ... and if the output says something about a built-in you probably have the explanation right there. Other possible outputs would be the path to some binary, a function of the name or an alias of the name (hope I didn't forget one). According to the `dash` man page you have `shell functions, builtin commands, and normal programs` there. The builtin `command` would allow you to refer to the command (e.g. `/bin/read`) ... simply say `command read`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [standard `read` utility](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html) takes *at least one* variable's name.

Some shell's `read` implementation uses a *default* variable, like `REPLY`, to store the read data if no name is supplied, but `dash`, aiming to be a POSIX compliant shell, does not (as it's not required to do so by the standard).  The equivalent in the `dash` shell would be

```
read REPLY
```

---

The `bash` shell, even in its POSIX mode, *does* keep some non-POSIX features enabled.  This is one of them, which means that `read` with no variable's name will work even if you run a `bash --posix` shell.

For a full list of things that happens when you enable POSIX mode in `bash` (which this question really isn't about), see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html